# scanning result of ibeacon on android never shown on the smartphone

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I'm trying to detect ibeacon using an android smartphone. I bought ibeacon devices from a company that has provided me android library to make them work (this library is much like the android beacon library for AltBeacon, such as the code that I used). Here is the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IBeaconConsumer {

private static final String TAG = "BB-EXAPP";

// iBeacon bluetooth scanning parameters
private static final int FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD = 1000;
private static final int FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD = 1000;
private static final int BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD = 250;
private static final int BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD = 2000;

// iBeacon Library Stuff
private static final Region blueupRegion = new Region("BlueUp", "acfd065e-c3c0-11e3-9bbe-1a514932ac01", null, null);
private IBeaconManager iBeaconManager = IBeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
private Intent iBeaconService;
private boolean isMonitoring = false;
private boolean isRanging = false;

// Android BLE Stuff
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;


// UI Stuff
private List<IBeacon> beacons;
private ListView listView;
private IBeaconListAdapter listAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initializes Bluetooth adapter
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    // Ensures Bluetooth is available on the device and it is enabled. If not,
    // displays a dialog requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth.
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    // Initializes iBeacon Service
    iBeaconService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IBeaconService.class);

    // Start the iBeacon Service
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting service: iBeaconService");
    startService(iBeaconService);

    // Set desired scan periods
    iBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD);
    iBeaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD);
    iBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD);
    iBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD);

    // Bind the iBeacon Service
    iBeaconManager.bind(this);

    //
    // UI Initialization
    //

    // Create Empty IBeacons List
    beacons = new ArrayList<IBeacon>();

    // Create List Adapter
    listAdapter = new IBeaconListAdapter(this, beacons);

    // Get ListView
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Set ListAdapter
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onIBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onIBeaconServiceConnect");

    // Set Monitor Notifier
    iBeaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.d(TAG, "didExitRegion: region = " + region.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {

            Log.d(TAG, "didEnterRegion: region = " + region.toString());

            // Set Range Notifier
            iBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {

                @Override
                public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<IBeacon> iBeacons, Region region) {
                    // Update UI iBeacons List
                    beacons = new ArrayList<IBeacon>(iBeacons);
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    // Log found iBeacons
                    Log.d(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion: region = " + region.toString());
                    if (!iBeacons.isEmpty()) {
                        int j = 0;
                        for (IBeacon beacon : iBeacons) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "  [" + j + "] (Major = " + beacon.getMajor() + ", Minor = " + beacon.getMinor() + ", RSSI = " + beacon.getRssi() + ", Accuracy = " + beacon.getAccuracy() + ")");
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            });

            // Start Ranging
            try {
                iBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(blueupRegion);
                isRanging = true;
                Log.d(TAG, "startRangingBeaconsInRegion: region = " + blueupRegion.toString());
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "startRangingBeaconsInRegion [RemoteException]");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Log.d(TAG, "didDetermineStateForRegion: state = " + state + ", region = " + region.toString());
        }

    });


    // Start Monitoring
    try {
        iBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(blueupRegion);
        isMonitoring = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion: region = " + blueupRegion.toString());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion [RemoteException]");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();
    if (iBeaconManager.isBound(this)) {
        iBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(this, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "iBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode = false");
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
    if (iBeaconManager.isBound(this)) {
        iBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(this, true);
        Log.d(TAG, "iBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode = true");
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

    if (isRanging) {
        try {
            iBeaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(blueupRegion);
            Log.d(TAG, "stopRangingBeaconsInRegion: region = " + blueupRegion.toString());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "stopRangingBeaconsInRegion [RemoteException]");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (isMonitoring) {
        try {
            iBeaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(blueupRegion);
            Log.d(TAG, "stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion: region = " + blueupRegion.toString());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion [RemoteException]");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (iBeaconManager.isBound(this)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Unbinding iBeaconManager");
        iBeaconManager.unBind(this);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Stopping service: iBeaconService");
    stopService(iBeaconService);

    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

There's a second activity to make the list:

```
public class IBeaconListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private List<IBeacon> beacons;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public IBeaconListAdapter(Activity _activity, List<IBeacon> _beacons) {
    this.activity = _activity;
    this.beacons = _beacons;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return beacons.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return beacons.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    /*IBeacon beacon = beacons.get(position);
    if (beacon != null) {
        return beacon.hashCode();
    }*/
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_list_row, null);
    }

    TextView majorTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.majorValue);
    TextView minorTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.minorValue);
    TextView rssiTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rssiValue);
    TextView accuracyTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.accuracyValue);

    IBeacon beacon = beacons.get(position);

    if (beacon != null) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
        majorTextView.setText(beacon.getMajor());
        minorTextView.setText(beacon.getMinor());
        rssiTextView.setText(beacon.getRssi() + " dBm");
        accuracyTextView.setText(df.format(beacon.getAccuracy()) + " m");
    }

    return view;
}

}
```

When I run the app on the phone, from the LogCat I can see that 
it detects the devices, while on the phone I can't see anything but a blank page! I noticed from the LogCat that once the onIBeaconServiceConnect is called, than the app jumps to the startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion and never calls the didEnterRegion method, which includes the didRangeBeaconsInRegion and the code to fill the list. 
I couldn't find other answers to a question similar to mine and I really don't know where is my mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by "from the LogCat I can see that it detects the devices"?  Can you post what you are seeing in LogCat that makes you think this?

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

1. Make sure your beacons are really transmitting and have the identifiers you think they do.  Try downloading an off-the-shelf app like [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) and make sure it sees them.
2. Your code sets up a region that is looking for a beacon with a UUID of `acfd065e-c3c0-11e3-9bbe-1a514932ac01`.  Are you sure this is exactly right?  Try replacing the region definition with `Region("BlueUp", null, null, null);` so it detects any region regardless of identifier.
3. If you plan to do significant development, I would strongly recommend you upgrade to the [Android Beacon Library 2.0](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/).  The old 0.x library version that library is based off of is no longer supported or maintained, and it will be more difficult to find help when problems like this come up.

Comment: I've already downloaded the app Locate and it sees them. I replaced the region definition as you said, but nothing changes, there's always that blank page. I'm using a library that is similar to the Android Beacon Library, but it detect beacons meeting the iBeacon spec. I tryed with the AltBeacon library but I didn't manage to use the BeaconParser to configure the library. Anyway, I've added an answer with the LogCat to show you the results.

Comment: Try setting iBeaconManager.debug=true; then capture a new logcat excerpt from the time the service connects to the first beacon detection.

Comment: Please see the Log in the other answers. from @arianna

Comment: This all looks right.  Sorry, I cannot explain why the didEnterRegion method does not get called.  Perhaps there is a problem with this fork of the beacon detection library

Answer (score 0):

These are the significant lines in the LogCat.

```
D/BB-EXAPP(7756): onIBeaconServiceConnect
D/BB-EXAPP(7756): startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion: region = proximityUuid: acfd065e-c3c0-11e3-9bbe-1a514932ac01 major: null minor:null
D/AbsListView(7756): unregisterIRListener() is called 
I/IBeaconService(7756): start monitoring received
D/BluetoothAdapter(7756): startLeScan(): null
D/BluetoothAdapter(7756): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=4
I/IBeaconService(7756): Adjusted scanStopTime to be Sat Jan 17 12:09:58 CET 2015
D/AbsListView(7756): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/BluetoothAdapter(7756): onScanResult() - Device=DA:0D:22:4B:40:17 RSSI=-59
D/Callback(7756): attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.android.appbeacon/com.blueup.libbeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}
D/BluetoothAdapter(7756): onScanResult() - Device=DA:0D:22:4B:40:17 RSSI=-64
I/IBeaconService(7756): iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :acfd065e-c3c0-11e3-9bbe-1a514932ac01 0 0 accuracy: 0.7351236323265571 proximity: 2
D/BluetoothAdapter(7756): stopLeScan()
```